# separate one form into 2 independent forms in symfony FOS

Tags: php, symfony, fosuserbundle

I created a login system in symfony with the possibility to register only for those who own a so called "client number", right now my problem is the registration form where user has basically to type in at first his client number which is going to be validated first if it exists in a database and then after submitting it, orm fetches some data about the company which possesses the client number and the application forwards user to another form where he has to type in other details like his username and password. So far right now I have it in one form and I created it after as being described in tutorial like with Registration Controller, Registration Form Handler and Registration Type, right now for example in Registration Type it looks like this

```
<?php
// src/AppBundle/Form/RegistrationType.php

namespace AppBundle\Form;

use Symfony\Component\Form\AbstractType;
use Symfony\Component\Form\FormBuilderInterface;
use Symfony\Component\Form\Extension\Core\Type\HiddenType;
class RegistrationType extends AbstractType{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options){

         $builder->add('name');
        // $builder->add('ClientNr'); <-- I want to check it in another form before i come to registration
         $builder->add('lanr');
         $builder->add('personal_key', HiddenType::class, array(
    'data' => $this->getID()));
    }

    public function getParent()
    {
        return 'FOS\UserBundle\Form\Type\RegistrationFormType';

        // Or for Symfony < 2.8
        // return 'fos_user_registration';
    }

    public function getBlockPrefix()
    {
        return 'app_user_registration';
    }

    // For Symfony 2.x
    public function getName()
    {
        return $this->getBlockPrefix();
    }
    public function getID()
    {
        return $random = random_int(10000,99999);
    }
```

as far as I know I have again to create files like "PreRegistration Controller, PreRegistrationFormHandler and PreType" or what are the exact steps to realize my idea?

Comment: Well, to be more exact these are the steps how I want it to be: 1. User comes to login dashboard and there are few links; forgot password and registration, after user clicks on registration he will be forwarded to "PreRegistration" 2. on Preregistration he has to type in his client number 3. and Then he can type in other details after submitting his Client number, thats where I'm struggling right now